# ng-content typed or with interface

Tags: angular, ng-content

I'm trying to figure out if it is possible to have typed ng-contents in Angular. What I'm trying to do is the following:

I'm inside a component that has an ng-content tag.

```
<div>
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

What I'd like to have is

```
<div>
  <ng-content (buttonClicked)="doSomething($event)"></ng-content>
</div>
```

So inside my component I only want to be able to put components that have the buttonClicked EventEmitter (maybe making sure through an interface)

Is this possible in Angular?

Comment: `ng-content` displays everything inside of the body of your component, I highly doubt that you can control what's being placed there. It is a cool idea though, perhaps it can be solved using a directive?

Comment: directive on the parent component?

Comment: Hmm, even determining if ng-content was provided is open GitHub issue. Expect answer may be no. https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/26083